# Getting rid of Facebook app invitations

Tags: facebook

I am so frustrated about the annoying Facebook apps invitations and requests from friends and users in my Facebook account. Is there a way to remove them? I haven't had much luck trying it on my own.

Comment: You're not really giving us a lot of information to work with here. Where are you getting these invites? Your PC, smartphone? Are they in your email or are you seeing these in Facebook itself? Perhaps the mailman keeps delivering you snail mail inviting you to Facebook ;) Without more details, we can only guess. Consider making an [edit] to your post to add the full details of your specific problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Yes, the above description s/could be expanded as I initially had the same doubts as you.. For now I took my own experience as a use case and went ahead.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

@Atif have you tried the following..

> Go to Privacy Settings > Block Lists > Block app invites. Type the names of friends you want to block from sending you app invites and press enter. Once you block app invites from someone, you'll automatically ignore future app requests from that friend. To block invites from a specific friend, click the "Ignore All Invites From This Friend" link under your latest request.

1. Click on the top-right dropdown button > Privacy Settings > 'Ads, Apps and Websites' Edit settings > And then in the 'Apps you can use' section click on 'Turn off..'

> Turn off your ability to use apps, plugins, and websites on and off Facebook. After you turn this off, we will not store information about you when you use apps or websites off Facebook.

WARNING: This will disable all your current apps (including all sites where you have used FB to login) and should prevent you from getting further app request.

Let us know if it works as expected.

Reference: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=202866049749634#

Comment: Well I usually go and clikc on the *ville FBapp request and then block all future request.. But I have not tried the latter which should disable ALL future app request too :)

Of course I cant try it out on my account :P using too many apps rite now!